# if-else spipping search strategy in LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to filter multiple attribute from the database. I am filtering with 3 attributes. Which may be empty or a key in any combination. I have tried this code, It working fine when I filtered in three steps,

```
IEnumerable<Employee> ItemsList = _db.Employees.AsEnumerable().Where(e => e.Role == 2).OrderByDescending(e => e.EmployeeID);
 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchKeyByName))
            {
                ItemsList = ItemsList.Where(e => e.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchKeyByName.Trim().ToLower()) || e.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchKeyByName.Trim().ToLower()) || (e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName).ToLower().StartsWith(SearchKeyByName.Trim().ToLower()));
                ViewBag.Search_FullName = SearchKeyByName;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchKeyByDepartment))
            {
                ItemsList = ItemsList.Where(e => e.Department.DepartmentTitle.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchKeyByDepartment.Trim().ToLower()));
                ViewBag.Search_Department = SearchKeyByDepartment;
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchKeyByDesignation))
            {
                ItemsList = ItemsList.Where(e => e.Designation.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchKeyByDesignation.Trim().ToLower()));
                ViewBag.Search_Designation = SearchKeyByDesignation;
            }
```

But I want to minimize this 3 if condition with LINQ, I have tried 1 of this using this code

```
IEnumerable<Employee> ItemsList2 = (from e in _db.Employees.AsEnumerable() 
                                               where e.Role == 2
                                                where (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchKeyByName) && (e.FirstName.Trim().ToLower().StartsWith(SearchKeyByName.Trim().ToLower()) || e.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(SearchKeyByName.Trim().ToLower()) || (e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName).ToLower().StartsWith(SearchKeyByName.Trim().ToLower())))
                                                select e).OrderByDescending(e => e.EmployeeID);
```

But the filtering result is being null/empty. 1st one is working well. Mention that, The search key may be empty, then it need to peek up all values but when key is provided then it will take only key findings one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `&&`; you are requiring that `SearchKeyByName` is always not empty/null by using that. Your filter should keep all records if `SearchKeybyName` is null or missing or use it in the search otherwise: `SearchKeyByName.IsNullOrEmpty() || (rest of it)`. But in this case, you can even simplify that out by using null coalescing, since every string starts with the empty string:

```
var ItemsList2 =
    from e in _db.Employees
    let loweredSearch = (SearchKeyByName ?? "").Trim().ToLower()
    where 
        e.Role == 2
        && (
            (e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName).ToLower().StartsWith(loweredSearch) 
            || e.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(loweredSearch)
        )
    orderby e.EmployeeID descending
    select e;
```

But this is probably more efficient:

```
var ItemsList2 =
    from e in _db.Employees
    let loweredSearch = (SearchKeyByName ?? "").Trim().ToLower()
    where 
        e.Role == 2
        && (
            loweredSearch == string.Empty
            || (e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName).ToLower().StartsWith(loweredSearch) 
            || e.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(loweredSearch)
        )
    orderby e.EmployeeID descending
    select e;
```

Comment: Thank you - [@Jacob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/119549/jacob) . it's working fine, but what about next 2 filters? how may I filter them?

Comment: Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(loweredSearch)` in stead of `loweredSearch == string.Empty` may be a good solution, because it may be a empty string.

Comment: @ShoumenAgdm, you'll just add them to the `||` chain.

Comment: Thanks @Jacob, I added them in && chain, cuz all filtering are need at a time. It's working fine. :D

Comment: @AnandaM.Ghosh, (SearchKeyByName ?? "") makes sure it's never null, so checking for empty string is all that's needed.

Comment: @Jaob Sure you are right. But I am trying to avoid an extra checking.